# can we send system message to offline users in QuickBlox?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

i am developing an `ios` app integrating it with `QuickBlox` and i am not using APNS in it. I am using systemMessage service for notifying the newly added members about they are joined to the specific group. The problem is systemMessage notifications are works only for the online users, if a person is offline it didn't work. So can i use any other way for sending notification for offline users without using systemMessage notification service as i am not using APNS.

Answer (score 0):

You are not able to send any notification without APNS if application is not running. In that case you definitely should use APNS.

Comment: i am dealing with the notifications by means of the chatDidReceiveSystemMessage, chatRoomDidReceiveMessage and chatDidReceiveMessage delegates. i am not using APNS.